# Yodlee API, Search for Sites in a country

Tags: api, yodlee

I would like to be able to restrict search to Financial Institutions that operate in a country.

We are a FinTech company operating in Australia and would like to initially find Financial Institutions relevant to our Australian clients

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, in your dedicated environment. You should talk to Yodlee support team. Yodlee support team will be able to explain more about in what scenarios it can happen.